# RHEL6 LDAP client not listing all the groups

Tags: linux, rhel, ldap

Using sssd I have a RHEL6 client configured to login using LDAPS. The login works, but if the user logged in is assigned to more than 1 group at the LDAP level, groups only returns 1 group?

Could I be missing a configuration somewhere?

The group shown is the default group assigned to the user. In RHEL5 clients, the group command displays all the groups that are assigned to the user.

Comment: Might be worth skimming this article for some guidance: http://www.couyon.net/1/post/2012/04/enabling-ldap-usergroup-support-and-authentication-in-centos-6.html